# Debugging with IIS 7.5 sometimes hangs

Tags: delphi, iis, iis-7, delphi-7

I am using Delphi 7 pro and debugging an older ISAPI app with IIS 7.5 (Windows 7).

Everything works fine except that if I place my cursor over a property to see the current value, sometimes Delphi will just display "evaluating" and hang - the only thing I can do at this point is reset the program.

Does anyone know if there is a setting I can adjust to prevent this hanging?

Comment: if you're running D7 on win 7, remember when you installed d7 that windows warned about compatibility problems, I'd test the app within a windows xp Vm

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo D7 runs fine on win7

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have been using VMWare with an XP VM - works ok but the performance is slow and spotty even though I have a SSD.  Windows XP VM is really slow.  D7 seems like it is constantly trying to save or something - painful

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, but there may be special circumstances in which the debugger and/or IDE fails, I also use D7 on W7 from time to time.

Comment: @user3396999 is your system an AMD without virtualization support by any chance? that would explain the slowness, I'm running games in VM's without problems on HDD not SSD.

Comment: Seems to be an incompatibility of the Delphi version with newer Windowses. We have the same issue here when debugging ISAPIs, since (IIRC) Vista. It happens only at some typical places, like string properties. You learn to live with it. You know, these old Delphi versions are restarted quickly after killing them the hard way. Only bad thing about it is the loss of your breakpoints, etc.

Comment: Thanks @user3396999 - I don't use AMD and I do have virtualization turned on.  The computer is very fast it is just that running D7 on XP in the VMWare (10) workstation pauses often for 30-45 secs even if no source code has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Check these settings:

- Is the ISAPI dll running in a separate dedicated Application Pool?
- Is "Maximum Worker Processes" set to 1?
- Is the "Identity" set to a *normal* user, preferably your own account or the account you run the Delphi debugger with?
- (If the ISAPI dll is 32-bit running on a 64-bit server: Is "Enable 32-bits applications" set to "True"?)
- Are limits, timeouts and intervals set high enough or disabled so IIS won't try to recycle the worker process while you're debugging.

Comment: As a side note: I've noticed that using the Delphi debugger on IIS does indeed also interrupt the internal workings of IIS causing unwanted behavior. One of the reasons I started the http://xxm.sf.net/ project was to be able to use the Delphi debugger on a web application, and to be able to use the same compiled binary in several environments: directly in InternetExplorer or xxmHttp for debugging, or with IIS or Apache on a live server.